# Laravel 6, passing multiple arrays from a controller to a view

Tags: laravel

I'm brand new to Laravel, I need to display around 8 different drop down menus on a page all populated from tables in my Db, I am using blades.

In my controller I can create various types of arraysin one function (using eloquent) and I can `dd();` them out correctly one at a time, my issue appears to be that you can only pass one array through a controller to a view. I have tried various options I found here but without success, including `->with` and `compact()`. I have tried defining the arrays in the controller one at a time and passing them using `compact()` all result in errors either the variable not defined or trying to get an non-object. I am obviously going about this all wrong any help would be great.

This is not a code issue (hence no code posted) I think it more of a Laravel issue that I don't yet understand, thanks in advance.

Comment: please put some code here.

Comment: you must show the code for how you passed data to blade using `compact()`, because you can pass unlimited array to blade file using compact()

Comment: You say there no code to post, but you also say you have tried different things. Maybe post some of the things you tried? `with` and `compact` are correct methods of sending as many arrays as you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend taking the tour and reading through How to Ask and related help topics. Questions seeking debugging help should include a minimal reproducible example, your expectations (what should happen) and where your code, etc. falls short of that. This information (including error messages, etc.) should be included as text with images optionally used to add clarity. –

Comment: I have posted my route (from web.php) and my function below

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
class YourController extends Controller{
  public function yourMethod(){
    $arr1 = [];
    $arr2 = [];
    return view('view.name', ['arr1' => $arr1, 'arr2' => $arr2]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
$array1 = [...];
$array2 = [...];
```

Then you can:

```
return view('path.to.view', compact('array1', 'array2');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my route from web.php and my controller from ReservationContoller any help as to my the arrays wont pass would be great, many thanks.

```
Route::get('/client/{client}/reservation/{reservation}', 'ReservationController@getReservation');

public function getReservation($client, $reservation)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($client); 
    $reservation = Reservation::where('client_id', $client->id)->get();
    $company = Company::where('type', 'staghen')
    ->where('status', 'Active')
    ->orderBy('comp_name')
    ->pluck('comp_name', 'id'); 

    $cl = array(['client' => $client]);
    $res = array(['reservation' => $reservation]);
    $comp = array(['company' => $company]);

    return view('admin.reservations.reservation', compact('$cl', '$res', '$comp'));
}
```